# printing a list in exception

Tags: ocaml

I am new to OCaml and am writing a recursive program in OCaml which returns the n-th element of a list. However I need to display an informative error message, displaying a list, when the list is too short, like "( a b c ) does not have 5 elements".
Here's my code

```
    let rec nth_element n list =
       match list with
       | [] -> raise(Failure "")
       | a :: l -> match n with
              0 -> a
              n -> nth_element (n-1) l
```

I want to replace the 'raise(Failure "")' part with the required error message. Writing a function for the same didn't help as it returned the unit type whereas the int type is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to print the entire list in the error message?
If you only need to print the missing item count you could do it like this:

```
failwith (Printf.sprintf "The list is %d elements too short" n)
```

Comment: This should read `Printf.sprintf`. I cannot edit, the system tells me edits must change at least six characters...

Answer (score 1):

Anywhere you have an expression `e` in OCaml you can also have an expression `s; e` where `s` is an expression of type `unit`. Here's a function that just raises an exception:

```
let f () = raise (Failure "")
```

Here's a function that does the same, but writes out a message first:

```
let f () = Printf.printf "helpful message"; raise (Failure "")
```

As a side comment, this isn't particularly idiomatic OCaml. Why not put the helpful message *inside* the exception? Like this:

```
let f () = raise (Failure "helpful message")
```

Comment: Can I print the contents of "list" inside the raise parentheses? That's what I intend to do!

Comment: In general no, because then the type of element in the list will have to specified so you will lose out on polymorphism. Also note that `failwith x` is a short cut for `raise (Failure x)`

Comment: What rgrinberg is saying is that if you print the items in the list, you have to pick one type to print. And so the function will only work for that one type of item. Generally you want to avoid this; OCaml is fantastic partly because you can so easily write functions that work for any type (polymorphic functions).

Comment: Well, if you *really* want to print the list in the error message *and* want to keep the function polymorphic that's possible, but you'll need to add another argument: a function converting list element to strings.